# Is "An unfathomable chaos" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a blog where I describe a problem as leading to "an unfathomable chaos", which is being underlined by Grammarly plugin for Chrome. Is it a mistake on my behalf or Grammarly is getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Grammarly objects to the use of the word "chaos" as a countable noun, with a singular article "an".  Indeed "chaos" is normally uncountable.

It is possible to use chaos as a countable noun. So "an unfathomable chaos" is perfectly good English, and Grammarly is indeed getting it wrong. But perhaps you should consider rephrasing. It's not very clear how a problem could be "a chaos".

Comment: But since *an unfathomable chaos* is perfectly good English (even if it is doubtful as to whether it should describe problems), Grammarly is indeed getting it wrong

Comment: @James K I have corrected the question. The sentence was something like "... the problem leads to an unfathomable chaos...".